# Why one of my y-axis labels relabel correctly when I have called scaleToFit Method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I have added CPTSCatterPlot and CPTBarPlot for two CPTPlotSpaces in one graph.I have worten a method to reloadData for the graph but not working so correctly.I want two of graph reload the y-axis labels after I have called the ScaleToFit method. Here is my Code:

```
plotSpace1 = (CPTXYPlotSpace*)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
barPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:TJCOLOR1.CGColor] horizontalBars:_isHorizontal];
barPlot.identifier = @"Bar";
barPlot.delegate = self;
barPlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace1];
[plotSpace1 scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObject:barPlot]];
plotSpace2 = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc]init];
[graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace2];
scatterPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc]init];
scatterPlot.identifier = @"Scatter";
scatterPlot.delegate = self;
scatterPlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:scatterPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace2];
    [plotSpace2 scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scatterPlot]];
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;

    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.tickDirection =  CPTSignNegative;
    x.labelOffset = -20.0f;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    [self xlabelS:x];
    x.hidden = YES;
    //    x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:-3.0];

    y = [[CPTXYAxis alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.plotSpace = plotSpace1;
    y.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0);
    y.labelExclusionRanges = nil;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(-0.5);

    y.hidden = YES;

    y2 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    y2.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y2.plotSpace = plotSpace2;
    y2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
    y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat([_titleArray count]);
    y2.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
    y2.labelExclusionRanges = nil;
    y2.titleOffset = -10.0f;
    y2.labelOffset = -40.0f;
    y2.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y2.hidden = YES;
    y2.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    NSArray *axies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x,y,y2, nil];
//    [axies addObject:y2];
    graph.axisSet.axes = axies;
 - (void)reloadData
{
     [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAllAnnotations];
     [graph reloadData];
     [plotSpace1 scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObject:barPlot]];
     [plotSpace2 scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scatterPlot]];
     CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet =  (CPTXYAxisSet*)hostingView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
     CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
     [self xlabelS:x];
}
     - (void)xlabelS:(CPTXYAxis *)x
{
    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSInteger i = 0;
    for (NSString *date in _titleArray) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        CGFloat location = i++;
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalAdd(CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location), barPlot.barWidth);
        label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
        if (label) {
            [xLabels addObject:label];
            [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
        }
    }
    //    x.labelingOrigin = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);

    x.axisLabels = xLabels;
    y.plotSpace = plotSpace1;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat([_titleArray count] );
}
```

Only the right y-axies relabeled correctly.Was anywhere I code wrong?Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

The y-axis is tied to `plotSpace1`. It is independent of the other plot space. No matter how `plotSpace2` changes, it won't affect the y-axis. If you want to see both scales, you'll need to add another y-axis to `plotSpace2`.

Comment: How? I have already set my y.plotspace = plotSpace1 and y2.plotspace = plotSpace2,isn't this a right way to add the y-axis to plotspace?

Comment: Yes, but that isn't clear from the question. Can you show more of the setup code and explain what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Hi,eric.Have you see my details posted below my questions?

Comment: Does the bar plot request new data from the datasource after calling `-reloadData`? Does the new data cover a different y-range than the original data?

Comment: No,I called -reloadData after I have requested new data.Bar plot's data was correct only the y-axis labels didn't match the data after I have called -scaleToFitPlots method.It's ture my new data covered a different y-range than the original data cause the y-max might be 30 000 or 300.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted that would explain this issue. The call to `-scaleToFitPlots:` will cause the plot to retrieve the new data from its datasource before calculating the range. Make sure the datasource is returning the correct data.

Comment: I'm sure that my datasource is returning the correct data unless a [NSNumber numberWithFloat:] object effects.I can't find the issue too because the scatter plot is totally correct for me.

Comment: No, `NSNumber` is fine. Double-check the rest of the app and make sure you haven't accidentally switched the plot spaces or plots anywhere. Does the bar plot display the new data, even if the plot space and axis don't update?

Comment: Yes,bar plot displayed the new data,only my y-axies for bar don't update.